# Kubernetes Secrets - What is the purpose of type "Opaque" in secret definitions

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-security

In most examples about using secrets in Kubernetes, you can find similar examples:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
type: Opaque
data:
  username: User
  password: **********
```

What is the purpose of `type: Opaque` in the definition above? What other types (and for which use cases) are possible to specify there?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`type: Opaque` means that from kubernetes's point of view the contents of this Secret is unstructured, it can contain arbitrary key-value pairs.

In contrast, there is the Secret storing `ServiceAccount` credentials, or the ones used as `ImagePullSecret`. These have a constrained contents.

Answer (score 31):

All types:

```
SecretType = "Opaque"                                 // Opaque (arbitrary data; default)
SecretType = "kubernetes.io/service-account-token"    // Kubernetes auth token
SecretType = "kubernetes.io/dockercfg"                // Docker registry auth
SecretType = "kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson"         // Latest Docker registry auth
```

To learn more, see [Type of Secrets from the Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/).

Answer (score 4):

The source code lists all the types:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.14/pkg/apis/core/types.go#L4447

Answer (score -5):

looks like its read only value for clients, clients are not allowed to modify this value.

> This value MUST be treated as opaque by clients and passed unmodified
>   back to the serve

this page has the details in the resourceVersion filed.

---

### edit

link change here is the document info:

> resourceVersion  string   An opaque value that represents the internal
>   version of this object that can be used by clients to determine when
>   objects have changed. May be used for optimistic concurrency, change
>   detection, and the watch operation on a resource or set of resources.
>   Clients must treat these values as opaque and passed unmodified back
>   to the server. They may only be valid for a particular resource or set
>   of resources. Populated by the system. Read-only. Value must be
>   treated as opaque by clients and . More info:
>   https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#concurrency-control-and-consistency

<s>https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.9/</s>
 https://k8smeetup.github.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.9/

Comment: link: 404 Error!

Comment: fixed the links.